# Kendo React ComboBox does not scroll to the typed value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using a Kendo React ComboBox and when I'm typing something the item is highlighted on the combobox popup but it does not scroll. So the selected item is essentially not visible to the user.
Is there a property I'm missing or some other workaround?

[image]

Comment: Your question lac for some implementation code. Check if this can help, especially the filter part. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/filtering/

Comment: Although yr suggestion does not solve the issue of scrolling, it did help me. If you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's related with the filter settings, please check telerik examples here:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/filtering/